# vba excel change backcolor of dynamically created scrollbar

Tags: excel, vba

I am stuck with trying to change the backcolor of a programatically created scrollbar. I can create the control but I get the error:

```
438 error of object not supporting the property or method
```

Here's the code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Set s = ScrollBars.Add(630, 220, 220, 38) '(left,top,width,height)
    s.BackColor = RGB(100, 100, 100) 'error happens here
End Sub
```

Comment: Right Click on it, if you are asking about an ActiveX scrollbar that you have created yourself(since this will not be a recursive action). However, the BackColor property will change all the components of the scrollbar, not just the slider ("thumb"). 
If instead you are using a Forms scrollbar, I do not believe you can change the color.

Answer (score 0):

Well, perhaps I could have been slightly more specific with my question. At any rate, I needed to set the color of a programatically created ActiveX scrollbar. Here's what I came up with and it works:

Sub CustomScrollbar()

ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.ScrollBar.1", Link:=False, _
DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=300, Top:=225, Width:=10, Height:= _
60).Select

Selection.ShapeRange.ScaleWidth 10, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
Selection.ShapeRange.ScaleHeight 2, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft

ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("ScrollBar1").Object.BackColor = &HC00000

End Sub